# Firebase dynamic link invalid and blocked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I’ve implemented firebase email authentication in iOS. I’ve tested the functionality on 4 different iPhones, all running iOS 13.3.1, and it works in half of them and not in the other. For the half that don’t work, I receive an error message stating “Invalid Dynamic Link - Blocked”. I’m performing the same process on all iPhones and am connected to the same WiFi. I’m trying to understand what would cause this to happen? It’s clearly something on the phone that is preventing it from segueing back to the app after authenticating.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and in my case, it was that I didn't set the dynamicLinkDomain (it isn't on the firebase example).

```
let actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings()
actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: "https://XXXXXX.page.link")
actionCodeSettings.dynamicLinkDomain = "XXXXXX.page.link"
actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
```